# Is every finite field a quotient ring of ${Z}[x]$?

Tags: finite-fields

Is every finite field  a quotient ring of ${Z}[x]$? For example, how a field with 27 elements can be written as a quotient ring of ${Z}[x]$?

Answer (score 5):

It is the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $3$ over $\mathbf F_3$, for instance $x^3-x+1$. As $\mathbf F_3=\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, we have:
$$\mathbf F_{27}\simeq \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[x]/(x^3-x+1)\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[x]\simeq\mathbf Z[x]/(3\mathbf Z[x]+(x^3-x+1)\mathbf Z[x]).$$

Comment: Can it be generalized for $|F|=p^n$ as $$\mathbf F_{p^n}\simeq \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[x]/(x^{p^n}-x)\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[x]\simeq\mathbf Z[x]/(p\mathbf Z[x]+(x^{p^n}-x)\mathbf Z[x]).$$

Comment: @cps Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @cps: it doesn't work as is, because  $x^{p^n}-x$ is not irreducible. If you factor $x$ out, the quotient is not necessarily irreducible, and if it is, it is not necessarily irreducible over $\mathbf F_p$.

Comment: So what would be the possible generalization?

Comment: Using the primitive element theorem, any  finite extension of $\mathbf F_p$ is the quotient of $\mathbf F_p[x]$ by the minimal polynomial of a primitive element of $\mathbf F_{p^n}$. This polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbf F_p$, hence it is also irreducible over $\mathbf Z$. So  $\mathbf F_{p^n}$ is the quotient of $\mathbf Z[x]$ by the ideal generated by $p$ and this polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Every finite field has an order which is the power of a prime.

Every finite field of order $p$ is isomorphic to integers modulo $p$. Every finite field of order $p^k$ is isomorphic to polynomials over the field with *p* elements; modulo an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$. There are no other fields.

So yes. Taking $\mathbb Z[x]$ through first a quotient on $p\mathbb Z$, then on $d\mathbb Z[x]$ with $p, d$ prime/irreducible will yield a field.

Comment: "an irreducible polynomial of order $k-1$"?

Comment: Also, $p\mathbf{Z}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbf{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @fkraiem yes. An irreducible polynomial is not the product (under multiplication of polynomials) of any non-trivial polynomials of lesser order. Like a prime number, but in a different ring.

Comment: If by "order" you mean "degree", then this is false as well. $\mathbf{F}_{p^k}$ is the quotient of $\mathbf{F}_p[x]$ by the principal ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$, not $k-1$.

Comment: @fkraiem right, sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Every finite field $F$ (of characteristic $p$) is isomorphic to a suitable quotient $F=\Bbb{F}_p[X]/(f)$ where $f \in \Bbb{F}_p[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial. Let $\tilde{f} \in \Bbb{Z}[X]$ be any lift of $f$.

Then $F=\Bbb{Z}[X]/(p, \tilde{f})$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof, which does not presuppose any knowledge of finite fields, only elementary group and field theory. Fix a finite field $F$ with $n$ elements.

Write $F^\times$ for the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of $F$. I claim that this group is cyclic (this is essentially Artin's theorem, but I will include a proof here for completeness, and to keep things elementary).

> Note that $F^\times$ has $n-1$ elements, so the orders of its elements divide $n-1$. Now, let $m$ be the least number such that for all $x\in F^\times$ we have $x^m=1$. Now, since $F$ is a field, the polyniomial $x^m-1=0$ has at most $m$ distinct roots, so $m\geq n-1$, so $m=n-1$. Finally, note that orders of elements of a finite abelian group are closed under least common multiple (if $x$ has order $m_x$ and $y$ has order $m_y$, then $xy$ has order $\operatorname{lcm}(m_x,m_y)$). It follows that there is some $x\in F^\times$ of order $m=n-1$, so $F^\times$ is cyclic.

Now, given that $F^\times$ is cyclic, let $\alpha$ be its generator. Observe that there is a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbf Z[x]\to F$ such that $\phi(1)=1_F$ and $\phi(x)=\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ generates $F^\times$, it is easy to check that $\phi$ is onto, so $F\cong \mathbf Z[x]/\ker \phi$.